# Input attribute doesn't reflect changes

Tags: javascript, html, validation, attributes

I am currently working on a blockchain based web app. I have a number type input field which has a max value attribute. I want to dynamically fetch the number of candidates and set this number as the max value.

This is the js:

```
const updateMaxAttribute = async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);
  const candidates = await contractInstance.getAllVotesOfCandiates();
  const maxCandidates = candidates.length;
  var voteInput = document.getElementById('vote');
  voteInput.setAttribute('max', maxCandidates - 1);
};
```

This is the HTML code: `<input id="vote" type="number" value="1" min="0">`

When I run this, `maxCandidates` is successfully being updated in the max attribute but the input field still takes input beyond what is allowed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The `max` attribute is really there to trigger validation - rather than prevent a user from inputting too large a number. If you really want to restrict the input, you can attach a JS listener ("input") to the field and run a check every time a keypress happens.
As shown in the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max) the max attribute will trigger pseudo classes (:invalid) which you can use to decorate your field as shown below. Many other validation options are available as well

```css
input[type=number]:invalid{
border-color:red
}
```

```html
<input id="vote" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="3" />
```